# Android WebView first page not loading on start after destroy

Tags: android, webview, android-activity, webviewclient

I have a WebView and while it loads the page which takes some seconds I want to show something other than a white screen, so I'm loading static data before loading the first page

> webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("/", wait_html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");

Now, when I press the back button my activity is destroyed and when I restart it, more often than not, I get a warning like:

> webcore Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout

and my static content is not displayed but the page that is loaded after is displayed without problems. So... any suggestions on how to make it show my static content?

Comment: I didn't get your question perfectly but if you facing problem with back button then ..just detect the key (back key) and display result as you want.

Comment: Actually the problem is not with the back button, but with destroying the activity and starting it again. Then when it passes through the oncreate and onresume, the line shown above should render static content, but instead the warning is displayed in logcat and the static content is not displayed. Instead, the screen remains white until it renders a new webpage I request.